# Does anybody recognize this journal/LaTeX template?

Tags: templates, article

I like the following LaTeX template or journal template, and I was wondering if anybody could recognize it. I believe that it is commonly used in certain areas of pure mathematics/analysis, likely for a well-known journal.

Here are the table of contents generated via the first page:

[image: ToC]

and here is a random section showing the section and subsections. I notice that this article format is distinguished with almost paragraphical numbered divisions.

[image: Sections]

Comment: It seems like it would be helpful to know which journal you took this from.

Comment: I should have checked this myself, but it was published in the Archive for the History of the Exact Sciences (https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133712), which is a Springer journal. However their currently provided LaTeX does not reflect the style seen in that 1984 paper.

Comment: If it's from 1984, there may not be a TeX template.  Is there some aspect of the template that you'd like to reproduce?

Comment: I think it is AMS-based article.